# problem using enum in another cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi I a have created a global.h file in which I define enum Token 
I get the garbage value of token if I use the value of Token other than glabal.cpp file 
I have also include the "global.h" file in other file where I am using the Token value how can I correct this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could post code?  That would help us figure out what you're encountering.

Comment: Don't want to bash people with not-so-good English, but there has to be time for punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct in assuming that your problem is that you don't want to include global.h in each of your files...

You need to include the enum in any source file you use it from.  [You cannot forward declare an enum](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/93/forward-declaring-enums-in-c).

Comment: i am including global.h in all files where i am using Token enum 
but i get the garbage value for token